# SFTP does not list correct directory or permissions

Tags: ssh, sftp

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and wish to host a sftp server where the user only has access to their home directory.

I have added this to sshd_config and restarted ssh:

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/ftp_user
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I can confirm that all of /home/ftp_user is owned by ftp_user, and that ftp_user is a member of the group sftp.

I can sftp in via both bash and filezilla as user ftp_user.  However, when I do, the directory /home is listed, but /home/ftp_user is permission denied.

This is not the behavour I expect.  I would expect /home/ftp_user to be listed first, and I would expect it to be accessible.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you've not applied security fixes? as a fully upgraded 18.04 system reports as [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) not 18.04.2, with that showing you've not applied security fixes since before [2019-August-8th](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/)

Comment: I'll look into that - this is an instance I just started on AWS with a Ubuntu 18.04 install.

Comment: I've run apt upgrade and afterwards it still reports Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS